# Are measures taken to deliberately increase the fuel burn rate to lower the landing weight?

Tags: emergency, fuel-consumption, fuel-dumping

Just recently the Air Canada flight AC837 from Madrid to Toronto had problems with the gear right after take-off and they decided to abort the flight and go back to Madrid. It was a B767-300 (C-GHOZ) which, AFAIK, cannot *dump* fuel so they circled approximately four hours southeast of Madrid in order to *burn* the fuel before landing:

[image]

(Source: Flightradar24, https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/ac837#23be1953)

Four hours is quite a long time and I wonder if the pilots actively do something to increase the rate at which fuel is burnt to somehow speed up the whole process. Like running the engines at full thrust and/or putting speed brakes/flaps in place. I don't know if they retracted the gear (which dramatically decreases the fuel consumption), but I doubt so because its damage was the whole reason for the circling.

If it matters: they circled approx. 1h @4500 ft and then approx. 2h 45m @7500 ft before heading back in Madrid.

Comment: Yeah I'd say so.

Comment: This is a good case illustrating the possible dupe. If not understood as a dupe, it can be understood as "what are the measures taken in this specific occurrence?"

Comment: @ManuH I agree it is a duplicate. I am not interested in the measures taken in this particular case, it merely triggered my curiosity. I haven't seen the other question. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @JohnK So do I. I just VTC as dupe. Or is deletion the preferred action?

Comment: @PerlDuck as the OP, I believe your VtC will auto-close the question. Deletion isn't necessary